# how to put a welcome message "username" using seesion with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the code for login.php and home.php
i want to know on how can i put a welcome message to my home.php like for example after i sucessfully login i will be redirected to home page and there be be a welcome message like welcome then the username..usi9ng seesion with PDO..can some body hel me with this..
here's my code for inde.php,login.php and home.php

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) &&  count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) {
echo '<ul style="padding:0; color:red;">';
foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
    echo '<li>',$msg,'</li>'; 
}
echo '</ul>';
unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
?>
<form action="reg.php" method="POST">
Username<br>
<input type="text" name="uname" /><br>
Password<br>
<input type="password" name="pword" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
// configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "pdo_ret";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// new data

$user = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['pword'];

if($user == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Username';
$errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
$errflag = true;
}

// query
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= :hjhjhjh AND    password= :asas");
$result->bindParam(':hjhjhjh', $user);
$result->bindParam(':asas', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
 if($rows > 0) {
header("location: home.php");
}
else{
$errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
$errflag = true;
}
if($errflag) {
$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
session_write_close();
header("location: index.php");
exit();
}

?>
```

**home.php**

```
<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:50px;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;">
Congrats!<br>
You've Benn Successfully Entered<br>
In The<br>
System<br>
</div>
```

Comment: *Easy as pie* - now, what have you tried?

Comment: can you help me about that..because i really can't figure out on how can i do it..

Comment: there is no relation between PDO and Session, both are used for different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this before you call `header("location: home.php");`

```
$_SESSION['welcome_msg'] = "WELCOME " . $user; //
```

Then, in home.php, `start_session()` and then echo `$_SESSION['welcome_msg']` to where you want it to be.

If you want to add breaks to your welcome message, you can always add `<br />` inside the message string.

Basically, its the same thing you did with your error msg. So you already knew this I guess.

EDIT:

home.php

```
<?php 
      session_start();
?>
<div>
<p>
     <?php echo $_SESSION['welcome_msg']; ?>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i think it should be session_start(); not start_session

Comment: i tried your instruction but its not working

Comment: yea it's session_start(). It is supposed to work. Did you set the $_SESSION['welcome_msg'] before header()? Did you start a session in home.php?

Comment: yes..i set the session before the header..but its not working..here's what i've done..// query
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM survey_login WHERE username= :hjhjhjh AND password= :asas");
$result->bindParam(':hjhjhjh', $user);
$result->bindParam(':asas', $password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['welcome_msg'] = "WELCOME " . $user; //
header("location: home.php");
}
else{
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username and Password are not found';
    $errflag = true;
}

Comment: and this is for the home.php   <?php
session_start();
?>

<div style="text-align:center;margin-top:50px;font-family:arial;font-size:20px;">
 <?php
 $_SESSION['welcome_msg']
?>
 Congrats!<br>
 You've Benn Successfully Entered<br>
 In The<br>
 System<br>
</div>

Comment: `its not working` - update your question with the changed code and what is not working? Not seeing a message, not redirecting .. Problem solving starts with properly identifying what goes wrong, start with that.

Comment: @kierrulfacabado dude, you're missing `echo` before $_SESSION['welcome_msg'] in home.php. check my edit